# How do I tie a delete button to a delete request?

Tags: html, angular

I have a html file that displays elements from a GET request using ng for, I have a red delete button displayed beside each element that is displayed and when clicked I want the element to be removed from the mongo database(triggering the delete). I have the DELETE set up in expressjs and everything but I want to know how do I tie the button to the appropriate element in the list? it loads in the browser like below:

```
detalis - unique_id                        del_button
detalis - unique_id                        del_button
detalis - unique_id                        del_button
```

Here is my component:

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
   messages: Message[] = [];

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.messageService.getMessages()
            .subscribe(
                messages => this.messages = messages,
                error => console.error(error)
            );
            console.log(this.messages);
    }

    onDeleteMessage() {
       this.messageService
      .deleteServiceWithId("Id", "8631")
      .subscribe(
          result => console.log(result),
          error => console.error(error)
        );
    }

}
```

HTML thats used as template:

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" [attr.id]="'accordion_' + i" *ngFor="let message of messages; let i = index;">
        <div class="panel panel-default" >
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-parent]="'#accordion_' + i" [attr.href]="'#collapseOne_' + i">{{ message.firstName }} {{ message.lastName }}</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div [attr.id]="'collapseOne_' + i" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  details here {{ message.empId }} 
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" aria-label="Left Align" (click)="onDeleteMessage()">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post what you have in message .if you have any error in console post that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each delete button pass in the id of the message to be deleted to the onDeleteMessage().

```
<!-- I'm not sure what the name for each id is but I'm assuming 
     its empId from the template you provided -->
<button class="btn btn-danger"
        aria-label="Left Align"
        type="button"
        (click)="onDeleteMessage(message.id)">
</button>
```

Then your component function

```
onDeleteMessage(id: Number) {
   this.messageService
       .deleteServiceWithId(id)
       .subscribe(
          result => console.log(result),
          error => console.error(error)
   );
}
```

Comment: Oh ok was Im new to angular2 and was overthinking this, thanks.